# How can I change a bit depth of video to 1 bit per color (meaning save video file format contains 3bit in total)?

Tags: video, conversion, file-formats, compression, bitrate

How can I change the depth of video to 1 bit per color (meaning 3bit in total). Normally video file format depth is 8 bit but I want 3bit. Actually i want the final video file to contain 3 bits per pixel when it saves, no matter how many colors are reduced **but i want the video file to be saved in 3 bits (1bit per color) to significantly reduce the video file size if i change the depth of video to 3bits.** and it doesn't matter what format mp4, avi, mkv, etc, etc. is this possible ?